# BIRT Report - Gantt Chart: Opening a Modal popup on Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, report, birt, gantt-chart

I am new to BIRT but I have looked for a solution everywhere before putting my question here and didn't find a solution.
I have a requirement where I want to open a popup when the user clicks (Left mouse click) on a bar Gantt chart. I want display the details about the product that is related to the bar in the chart.

Would appreciate if somebody can tell me how to go about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have a bit of data show on mouse over, I have not done it in a while, and can't recall how it works.

Here is a screen shot of an old ugly thing I built some time ago. With the mouse over circled.

[image]

For a full popup you would need to do something like a Drilldown, where clicking opened a new report in a new window.  I am assuming that you want the report with the Gantt chart to stay in place and that you want the "popup" to have several column and/or rows of the data that is related to your chart.

This probably could have been a comment, but you can't put the screen shot in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James. Yes, I tried Mouse Over but it does not help for my requirement. Going to a new page would be a last resort. What I am trying to do is to open a Modal kind of popup to display the details.

Comment: In theory with BIRT you can do anything that you can write Java or JavaScript for, there is nothing out of the box that will give you a popup.  BIRT runs a query, figures out how to display the results as HTML and renders it as a web page; Done.  Everything after that is a new report call, Drill downs in BIRT work as a hyper link that sends parameters to a report that you built separately.

Comment: Right, I have implemented drill down feature to link two reports (something like master-detail) but that's not what I am looking for here. I already have the data on my report just need to display it in a Modal popup when the user clicks on the chart. Any pointers to achieve that?

Comment: no problem, I will keep looking. :) Thanks for giving your time, appreciated.

Comment: Actually there is also an "Invoke script" action that allows to do such things. I haven't used it for ages, but here is an article with a complete example: http://birtworld.blogspot.fr/2009/12/calling-client-side-javascript-from.html

Comment: @Gauzy if you did not get called to it, see the comment above

Comment: Dominique, @James - I got onto another project and this fell off the radar. Just wanted to reply to both of you and say thanks. The link Dominique sent looks something similar to what can use, I will certainly look into it when I get on BIRT project back. :) I really appreciate your help.